# Extending Validation Library - CI2

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation

I need a to set up a validation for student ID's and the CI native library is not cutting it, so I extended. I however am having an issue getting it work, and I don't quite know where I am goofing up. This is my first crack at REGEX so go easy on me. Here is my Code :

```
<?php

 if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
 {

     public function is_valid_student_id($str)
     {
         if(strlen($str) > 9)
         {
             $this -> set_message('is_valid_student_id', 'A-Number can not be over 9 characters');
             return FALSE;
         }
         elseif(strlen($str) < 9)
         {
             $this -> set_message('is_valid_student_id', 'A-Number can not be under 9 characters');
             return FALSE;
         }
         elseif((($str[0]) !== 'a') && (($str[0]) !== 'A'))
         {
             $this -> set_message('is_valid_student_id', 'A-Number must begin with the letter "A"');
             return FALSE;
         }
         elseif(ctype_alpha($str[0]))
         {
             if(is_numeric(substr($str, 1, strlen($str) - 1)))
             {
                 return TRUE;
             }
             else
             {
                 $this -> set_message('is_valid_student_id', 'A-Number must have 8 digits 0 - 9');
                 return FALSE;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             $this -> set_message('is_valid_student_id', 'A-Number must begin with the letter "A"');
             return FALSE;
         }

     }

 }
```

Then to use the validation I do this :

```
if (!$this->input->post('student') == 'yes') {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('anum', 'A Number', 'required|is_valid_student_id|exact_length[9]');
}
```

I've been following these [good](http://www.witheringtree.com/2011/09/custom-codeigniter-validation-methods/) /// [tutorials](http://www.noupe.com/php/php-regular-expressions.html), but I am still a little confused. Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: You should just run a single `preg_match()` for this rule, and if it fails, have your error message contain the requirements for the number. That's a lot of extra logic for a single string validation.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you on that! However my boss doesn't - lol. He wants the student to know exactly why their student ID is not working. With my level of PHP knowledge this was the easiest way on how to get that user requirement met. At least now, every single mess up on the students part when it comes to typing is predicted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `callback_` syntax, then the function called needs to be on the controller. If you're adding it to the `Form_Validation` library directly, though, you don't need `callback_`. Try this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
      'anum', 'A Number', 'required|is_anum|exact_length[9]');
```

Comment: On a side note: you may want to re-think that function name. When I see `is_anum`, I think it means "is alphanumeric" or something equivalent. Maybe "is_valid_student_id"?

Comment: I did what you said, removed the callback, and changed the function name, but I am still not able to get any validation errors.

Comment: Are you able to get *any* errors? If not, make sure that error reporting is turned on. If you are unit testing (if not, why not), then make sure that `is_valid_student_id` is returning what you expect, consistently.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting an inappropriate value in anum? (It would not be the first time that a field got overridden accidentally)

Comment: I just did a var_dump of $str and I got nothing to show. Could it be possibly because $str is an empty value / no value? And I turned on error reporting and no errors are shown.

Comment: What about `$_REQUEST['anum']`? Is there a value there? Are you sure the function is being run? Is `$_POST['student'] == 'yes'`?

Comment: Yes anum is populated the logic never changed in the controller. This is my output : string(9) "q11112222" which is very wrong since it has a Q rather then an A.

Comment: Are you sure that `is_valid_student_id` is being called?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30340/discussion-between-rixhers-ajazi-and-cwallenpoole)

Comment: DEBUG - 2013-05-21 10:40:42 --> Unable to find validation rule: is_valid_student_id

Comment: Netbeans didn't add the .php extension at the end of my file... and I don't know why... it does for all other files. Thanks for your help +1

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to extend the library just make one callback method in your controller and add above code in it...Just Make one method called is_anum and put your code In it

```
if (!$this->input->post('student') == 'yes') {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('anum', 'A Number', 'required|callback_is_anum|exact_length[9]');
        }

function is_anum($str)
{
if (((substr($str, 0) !== 'a') || substr($str, 0) !== 'A') && (!preg_match("/[^0-9]/", $str) )) // If the first character is not (a or A) and does not contain numbers 0 - 9 
        { // Set a message and return FALSE so the run() fails
            $this->set_message('is_anum', 'Please enter a valid A-Number');
            return FALSE;
        } else 
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```